# Split String into rows but keep associated data

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm not real familiar with Split_String and my searches aren't turning up anything that I can figure out for my case.

What I need to do is split a field into rows each time its delimited but then for each new row created, copy the associated columns with that field to those new rows.

**How data will start:**

| Name | TimeStamp | StudentIds | Category | ReportName |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Teacher Report Run | 2021-08-31 20:24:52.5430000 | 111111 | Teacher Reports | Report 1 |
| Teacher Report Run | 2021-08-30 1:01:22.1250000 | 222222,333333,444444 | Teacher Reports | Report 2 |

**What I need:**

| Name | TimeStamp | StudentIds | Category | ReportName |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Teacher Report Run | 2021-08-31 20:24:52.5430000 | 111111 | Teacher Reports | Report 1 |
| Teacher Report Run | 2021-08-30 1:01:22.1250000 | 222222 | Teacher Reports | Report 2 |
| Teacher Report Run | 2021-08-30 1:01:22.1250000 | 333333 | Teacher Reports | Report 2 |
| Teacher Report Run | 2021-08-30 1:01:22.1250000 | 444444 | Teacher Reports | Report 2 |

I was thinking Split_String but again, this is one area I haven't had to do much of yet so I'm very green. That time has come to an end.

Comment: A better approach would be to fix your design. When you store multiple values in a single tuple you are violating 1NF. Also, timestamp is a datatype which has nothing to do with date or time and using reserved words as column names is painful. It is also a pretty useless column name because it is so ambiguous.

Comment: I dont have that control. The table is a hash table storing what I believe is data injected either through JSON or XML. Table has over a trillion rows...

We are in talks to get this particular data pulled out more directly so its not part of this insanely huge table but the table is literally recording all requests made on our website which is used by thousands of schools. So, I get it. I hated this as soon as I saw it LOL

Comment: I feel your pain. Sometimes we are stuck with less than ideal constructs we can't fix. At least you have a solution below.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's how you would do it using `STRING_SPLIT` and `CROSS APPLY`.  Keep in mind that `STRING_SPLIT` does not guarantee row ordering in the results.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #t1;
CREATE TABLE #t1(
  [Name] VARCHAR(MAX),
  [TimeStamp] VARCHAR(MAX),
  [StudentIds] VARCHAR(MAX),
  [Category] VARCHAR(MAX),
  [ReportName] VARCHAR(MAX)
)
GO

INSERT INTO #t1 ([Name],[TimeStamp],[StudentIds],[Category],[ReportName])
SELECT 'Teacher Report Run', '2021-08-31 20:24:52.5430000', '111111', 'Teacher Reports', 'Report 1' UNION ALL
SELECT 'Teacher Report Run', '2021-08-30 1:01:22.1250000', '222222,333333,444444', 'Teacher Reports', 'Report 2'

SELECT #t1.Name, #t1.TimeStamp, sids.value StudentIds, #t1.Category, #t1.ReportName
FROM #t1
CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(StudentIds, ',')  sids
```

Comment: haha was about to post a nearly identical answer. Faster on the keyboard

Comment: This answer will work for your current design, but you should note @SeanLange 's comment on your question.  This does usually indicate a desgin flaw...

Comment: Not a design flaw per say, considering the base data is being pulled from a hash table storing JSON/XML data that is recording every single action happening on our website which is used by thousands of teachers and students. Theres over a trillion rows...hence why its being stored like that (or so the Dev has told us).

Comment: Thanks squillman! Works great. I'm able to extract the data from this huge table into a CTE and then run this against that CTE to get the result I need. That was way simpler and more elegant than I thought it would be.